# ScrollSpy working on localhost, not on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I'm developing an ASP MVC application with ScrollSpy on one of my pages.  I'm having a strange problem where it's working correctly when I run my site from localhost, but when I publish the application to a server, ScrollSpy isn't adding the `active` class to the `<li>` items.

This is the script on my page which initializes ScrollSpy.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').attr("data-target", "#side-nav");
            $('body').attr("data-spy", "scroll");
        });
    </script>
}
```

Here's how my ScrollSpy navigation is defined.

```
<div id="side-nav" class="pull-left">
    <ul class="affix nav nav-list nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#first-section">First Section</a></li>
        <li><a href="#second-section">Second Section</a></li>
        <li><a href="#third-section">Third Section</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Each section has an anchor tag defined like this

```
<a class="anchor" id="first-section"></a>
```

I verified that jquery.js and bootstrap.js are referenced correctly on the server by going to View Page Source and clicking on the link to view the .js file.  I tried replacing the .min versions of the files with the same .js file that's being used on localhost, but that doesn't work.

I apologize in advance for this being a difficult to recreate problem.  Please tell me if I should post any additional data to make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are you sure `body` tag style `position` set to `relative`. Is there any css on the production server that overwrite the `body` tag style? And make sure you have got `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the top of this page.

Comment: why don't you try `data-spy = "scroll"` and `data-target = "#side-nav" ` as an inline attribute on the `body` tag rather than the jQuery function. And see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Adding the `data-spy` and `data-target` as inline attributes worked.  Do you know what that was necessary for the remote server, but not for when I'm running the site on my local computer?  Even though it worked, I'd prefer to be able to solve this another way because the `<body>` tag is defined in my shared `_Layout.cshtml` partial view so not all pages will make use of it.

Comment: In answer to your other comment, yes I do have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the page, and the `body` tag does have its `position` set to `relative` (I verified through Chrome's Developer Tools).

Comment: Using `$("body").scrollspy({ target: "#side-nav" });` works, but I still don't understand why my original code worked locally, but not remotely.